# When you can look through a forest?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Yesterday I was coming back home by train through various forests and I realised, that through some of them one can see to the other side and through some of them not. Can this be formalised? That is, what is the chance of seeing what is on the other side of the forest depending on the size of the forest, average number of trees per unit area and the diameter of their trunk?

Comment: Depends a lot how the trees are arranged: is it a square lattice, a hexagonal (same as equilateral triangle) lattice, or otherwise? Different patterns of arrangement will give different answers

Comment: There's a highly-related Numberphile video called [Tree Gaps and Orchard Problems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-xa-3V5KO8). I highly recommend taking a look. You're definitely not the only one with such curiosities!

Comment: He talked about average numberof trees per unit area, so I think he means random uniform distribution.

Comment: It also depends critically on viewing distance. If there's a tree trunk right in front of your eyeball, you're very unlikely to see through the forest. :)

Comment: Can you refine the question a little? As I look at the forest, there are *some* directions I can see through, and others blocked by trees. If the train moves a little, other directions are blocked. Does "see through" mean "from every viewpoint there's SOME direction where I can see through? Or perhaps "from *some* viewpoint there's *some* direction I can see through? Would "parallel projection" be just as good as "perspective projection" (i.e., may we assume the train tracks are far from the forest edge, compared to the forest "depth")?

Comment: BTW, I think this is a great question-area, and I love the inspiration. I just want to be sure to answer the question you care about, rather than spending time on something else!

Comment: Is the arrangement of trees isotropic? OR the set of forests are also randomized?

Comment: There is a lot of literature on this. Type "orchard visibility problem" or "Polya's orchard problem" into Google, and see what comes back at you.

Comment: Have you followed up on my comment, Machinato?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, I have looked up the Pólya's problem and indeed it is very similar. However, the main difference is that in nature the position of trees in a forest is almost random. So appropriate model of my interest is a Poissonian distribution. That is, a number of centres of trees in a given area A should follow Poisson distribution with λ=nA, where n is an expected number of centers of trees in a unit area. If the areas are disjoint, the distribution should be independent.

Comment: @JohnHughes, I really like your partial answer you have written so far. It is very interesting that the problem can be viewed from different perspectives since the question itself possess different interpretations. I was myself imagining when trying to give it some more proper definition to translate the task into probabilistic terms. The field of view in a forest is 2π. At any instant, you see through α of it. When you move, α changes. I was particularly interested in case when α is zero most of the time and when that happens.

Comment: Glad my ramblings were of some use. I think one could phrase your question as "Given some disk $R$, what's the area of the subset $S$ of $R$ for which $\alpha = 0$?" As $R$'s diameter gets close to five or 10 times the typical tree-spacing, I suspect that $area(S)/area(R)$ approaches some constant that could be called the "darkness of the forest" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A partial answer, showing how someone who does this kind of thing regularly gets started on the process**

I hope that this "here's how I'm thinking through this" answer is of some value to you.

Here's a sketch of an answer to a very specific question that's at least closely related to yours.

Consider an long strip in the $xy$-plane, oriented along the $x$-axis, whose bottom edge extends from $(-L, 1)$ to $(L, 1)$, and whose top edge extends from $(-L, 1+a)$ to $(L, 1+a)$, where $L$ is some large number (compared to the diameter of a tree-trunk). This is my model of an overhead view of a forest of "depth" $a$ and extent $2L$. We're going to scatter trees of some fixed diameter $w < 1$ in this strip (with the tree-centers uniformly distributed in the $2L \times a$ rectangle, so the tree edges might extend a little outside of it), and imagine that the sun is just rising at $(0, \infty)$, casting rays towards the $x$-axis. The question then becomes, "What is the probability that the origin is not in the shadow of any tree-trunk?"

This amounts to asking "If the train stops and I look straight out at the forest, what is the probability that I can see through it?"

The nice thing about this model is that the shadow cast by a tree of diameter $w$ on the $x$-axis is just an interval of width $w$ (because the sun is effectively "infinitely far away"). Let's suppose that the tree "density" is $c$, so that within a forest region of area $A$, the expected number of tree-centers is $cA$.

If we're considering the origin as our "test point", the only trees than can possibly shadow us are those whose centers have $x$-coordinates between $-\frac{w}{2}$ and $\frac{w}{2}$, and $y$-coordinates between $1$ and $1 + a$ (because those are the $y$-limits of the forest). That's a region of area $aw$, so we expect there to be $caw$ trees in it.

To do this right, I should consider the number of trees in that region as a random variable, and then take an average over all possible values of that random variable, but I'm going to keep it simple (for now) and say that I've got $caw$ trees.

So my simplified problem is this: given $caw$ intervals of length $w$, with centers in $[-w/2, w/2]$, what's the probability that $0$ is not in any of them? Well...the probability is zero, because all those possible trees (assuming we use *closed* intervals) actually overlap the origin. The only subtelty here is that $caw$ might be much less than $1$, so when I say I "have $caw$ intervals", I might be saying to "consider $0.024$ intervals of length $w$ ...", and so on.

But wait: suppose that $caw$ is actually $1/7$ (just to pick a round number). That means that $1/7$ of the time (on average) there's a tree whose projection covers the origin, so $6/7$ of the time I can see through the forest! Aha! In this simple version where I say that "caw" is the number of trees, I get that $1 - caw$ is the probability I can see through the forest.

That's actually a pretty good approximation when $caw$ is small (say, less than $0.5$). But what if $caw = 1$? Then the average count of trees (in all imaginable forests) shadowing the origin is $1$. But in some of those, two or three trees might be shadowing the origin, and in others, *none* might be shadowing it. So we can't really say that the probability that the origin is unshadowed is zero. Hmmm.

In fact, at this point, you're asking a question analogous to this one: suppose I flip a fair coin $N>>1$ times. I expect the number $S$ of "heads minus tails" to be zero, which it is, *on average*. But what's the probability (as a function of $N$) that $S > 1$? or that $S > 2$? I.e., what fraction of the time is some random variable far from its average?

Feller's introduction to probability has a whole chapter on questions like this, but it's upstairs, and I need to go run errands, so I'm gonna stop here.